# Dynamic targets and id in composite component

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I have one composite component:

```
<composite:interface componentType="myCC">
    <composite:attribute name="tempId" required="false"/>
    <composite:attribute name="action" targets="??????" required="false"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
        <p:commandButton id="#{cc.attrs.tempId}button" 
            action="#{cc.attrs.action}"/>
</composite:implementation>
```

In addition - I have two components that using it -

```
<span id="firstSpan">
    <sm:myCC id="fooid1" tempId="inFirstSpan"
      action="#{firstController.method('String')}"/>
</span>

<span id="secondSpan">
    <sm:myCC id="blaid1" tempId="inSecondSpan"
      action="#{secondController.method('String')}"/>
</span>
```

The problem is, that I tried to use the id inside the `targets` but it failed.

How can I implement this under those circumstances?

Comment: Why exactly do you need #{cc.attrs.tempId}? Just get rid of it and think in context of the composite (ignore the client) and everyting will point out by itself.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, first - thanks for the comment. Until now, the `commandButton` id was only `"button"` - which is working just great. But we got a demand from our client to change the `commandButton` id according to the `span` that wraps it, without changing the "clientId". Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

By default, your current approach shouldn't work because when JSF outputs the HTML for children components of composite composites, it will first include the composite component id, then a separator, then the child component id, like this:

Let's say the composite component ID is "ccId" and the child component is "ccChildId", the outputted ID will be like this:

```
ccId:ccChildId
```

Because of this, if you want to dinamically reference a child component ID you will have to composite your call including the parent ID to mirror the outputted HTML generated.

In your case, your target should be something like this:

```
targets="fooid1:inFirstSpanbutton"
```

Comment: First half of your answer is correct. Second half of your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Hi @BalusC it's been a while since my last interaction with JSF, would mind to please include the incorrect part so I can fix it?

Comment: @Bonifacio - Can you give an example according to my example? Do you mean to do - `<composite:attribute name="action" targets="#{cc.clientId}:#{cc.attrs.tempId}button" required="false"/>`?

Comment: Yeah this is what I've meant, but as @BalusC indicated, right now I'm not sure if it will work as expected.